# Child div auto resize to its parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a parent div . Inside it their are 3 divs one on the left side and other two on the right side . I need to increase the height of my left div as the content of the right div increases

```css
.jumbotron-r {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  height: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .jumbotron-r {
    padding: 7.5rem 2rem;
  }
}

.jumbotron-l {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .jumbotron-l {
    padding: 4rem 2rem;
  }
}

.jumbotron-fluid-l {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.letter-color {
  color: #fff;
}

.break {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1px;
}

.jumbotron-nav {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-5 ">
    <div class="jumbotron-r">
      <h1 class="letter-color">Left Div</h1>
      <p class="letter-color">Left Div content</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-7 ">
    <div class="jumbotron-l">
      <p class="letter-color">Right Div1 content</p>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-7 ">
    <div class="jumbotron-l">
      <p class="letter-color">Right Div2 content</p>
      <p><a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Left Div size must be same as the right div]

Specifying the height to a particular value is not possible for me . Because the contents may vary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally I was going to answer with the same solution as @Mihai-t but I realised a [css grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) solution, in my opinion, is more elegant and appropriate:

```css
#a {
  grid-area: a;
}

#b {
  grid-area: b;
}

#c {
  grid-area: c;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "a" 
    "b" 
    "c";
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  #container {
    grid-template-areas: 
      "a b" 
      "a c";
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #container {
    grid-template-areas: 
      "b a c";
  }
}

.item {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a" class="item">
    <h1>Left</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="b" class="item">
    <p>Right Top</p>
  </div>
  <div id="c" class="item">
    <p>Right bottom</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately `css-grid` isn't quite as well [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) as [`flex` is](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex), but like with `flex` you should just serve the mobile version to unsupported browsers.

This solution allows you to add as many layouts as you wish and place the objects in any order, which is what the additional media query demonstrates. Which is something you cannot achieve using `flex`.

Comment: Your Solution is so nice i am just a beginner thanks for your support

Answer (score 2):

You can make equal height columns with `display:flex` on row. So, you need to have both columns in the same row.

So make just 2 col-md-6 ( not sure why you added another one ) and use display flex when over 768px on the row

see snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38726/)

```css
.row-eq-height .col-sm-6:first-child .jumbotron-r {
  height: 100%;
}

.jumbotron-r {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  height: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .jumbotron-r {
    padding: 7.5rem 2rem;
  }
}

.jumbotron-l {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.jumbotron-l:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-eq-height {
    display: flex;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .jumbotron-l {
    padding: 4rem 2rem;
  }
}

.jumbotron-fluid-l {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.letter-color {
  color: #fff;
}

.break {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1px;
}

.jumbotron-nav {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-5 ">
    <div class="jumbotron-r">
      <h1 class="letter-color">Left Div</h1>
      <p class="letter-color">Left Div content</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-7 ">





    <div class="jumbotron-l">
      <p class="letter-color">Right Div1 content</p>

    </div>





    <div class="jumbotron-l">
      <p class="letter-color">Right Div2 content</p>
      <p><a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Button</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you . I am modify the code as this thank you for your help

Comment: When i add data to my left div the height of right div not varying . But left div varies with respect to right. Why it so

Comment: @Jks the height of the right div is equal to the left and viceversa . But on the right, you don't have a div that is 100% height of the column. THe columns are equal. ( just inspect them ) . use height:60% and height:40% on the 2 jumbotrons in right div and they will cover 100% height of their column

Comment: Ok i will try. Thank you for your replay

Comment: Is their any tutorial or any thing like that related to equal column height

Comment: @Jks you just search on google `bootstrap equal col height` . Not that complicated :) http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery
take a look at this plugin
https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

you give your divs the same class and this will match their height

```
<script>
      $(document).load(function() { 

        $('.same_height').matchHeight({ byRow:true });

      });
      </script>
```